# Best practice on structuring asynchronous mailers (using Sidekiq)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, sidekiq

Just wondering what's the best way to go about structuring asynchronous mailers in my Rails app (using Sidekiq)? I have one ActionMailer class with multiple methods/emails...

**notifier.rb**:

```
class Notifier < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "\"Company Name\" <notify@domain.com>"

  default_url_options[:host] = Rails.env.production? ? 'domain.com' : 'localhost:5000'

  def welcome_email(user)
    @user = user
    mail to: @user.email, subject: "Thanks for signing up!"
  end

  ...

  def password_reset(user)
    @user = user
    @edit_password_reset_url = edit_password_reset_url(user.perishable_token)
    mail to: @user.email, subject: "Password Reset"
  end
end
```

Then for example, the password_reset mail is sent in my `User` model by doing...

**user.rb**:

```
def deliver_password_reset_instructions!
  reset_perishable_token!
  NotifierWorker.perform_async(self)
end
```

**notifier_worker.rb**:

```
class NotifierWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  sidekiq_options queue: "mail"

  def perform(user)
    Notifier.password_reset(user).deliver
  end
end
```

So I guess I'm wondering a couple things here...

1. Is it possible to define many "perform" actions in one single worker? By doing so I could keep things simple (one notifier/mail worker) as I have it and send many different emails through it. Or should I create many workers? One for each mailer (e.g. WelcomeEmailWorker, PasswordResetWorker, etc) and just assign them all to use the same "mail" queue with Sidekiq.
2. I know it works as it is, but should I break out each of those mail methods (welcome_email, password_reset, etc) into individually mailer classes or is it ok to have them all under one class like `Notifier`?

Really appreciate any advice here. Thanks!

Comment: You can simply use: `Notifier.delay.password_reset(user)`. No need to create separate workers. See here: https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Delayed-Extensions

Comment: Bliss! That's awesome. Thanks for the reference. If you want to add that as an answer I'll accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [discussed here](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Delayed-Extensions), Sidekiq supports delayed mailer by default, so there is no need to create separate workers:

`Notifier.delay.password_reset(user.id)`

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure but I think its not a good idea to pass an instance in mailer action if you're using delay, so maybe its better to change the code above to :

```
Notifier.delay.password_reset(user.id)
```